# Logistic Regression - Problems with having fewer predictors than responses

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, multinomial-logit

In multinomial regression, is it theoretically possible to have issues with having fewer predictors than responses? I'm assuming all predictors are continuous for purposes of simplicity.

I am thinking in analogy to linear regression, wherein having too few predictors may cause the resulting linear system to be underdetermined. I mean this in the sense of the effective dimensions (degrees of freedom?) of the predictor being less than that of the response. If we view multinomial regression just as classification, this does not make sense, but if we view it as nonlinear regression I think it is less clear.

Note: this is substantially edited from the original posted question.

Comment: There is no problem with having less predictors than response classes. E.g. Suppose you have variables $Y = \text{letters A, B, ...}$, and the predictor $X = Y$. Then, you have perfect prediction capabilities running the regression $Y \sim X$.

Comment: @Alex Interesting point. I guess I don't really quite know how to make my idea precise, because I don't see that as a counterexample.

Comment: are you doing multinomial regression? You should be able to fit the model as long as you have enough variance in the 16 predictors combined. Can you post some example data and code?

Comment: For example, in `R`, the following code runs but the regression is nonsensical: `tmp_df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = letters[sample(1:3, 100, T)])`, then fit logistic model:
`m1 <- glm(y ~ x, data = tmp_df, family = 'binomial')`. You might want: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175782/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-for-more-than-2-response-classes-in-r instead.

Comment: `glm` in R coerces the first class/factor level to 0 and the rest to 1. It may be that whatever method you are using to do 'logistic' regression does the same. Please clarify whether you meant multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: I think what I'm doing is basically multinomial regression. I have not set it up the same way (I'm programming it in python), so it may not be quite right.

Comment: predicting one letter is symptomatic of the problem i just demonstrated, or otherwise you are not returning the class probabilities for all 26 classes. Post your code and an excerpt of the the data.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand. I'm not using R, so it couldn't be a problem with glm. Moreover, the model is not always predicting one letter, it is just usually predicting that letter (which letter is not consist).

Comment: Ok. I misinterpreted that bit. Can you get your predicted class probabilities 
 for each observation (all 26 classes), and then sum them across all observations to see what your expected observations of each class should be? And compare this to the actual distribution of classes in $y$.

Comment: @Alex The actual distribution is uniform, but the predicted distribution is decidedly not. Several average probabilities are near 1, and several are near 0. I think it may be a problem with gradient descent; if I recall, it doesn't work well with the logistic function.

Comment: As @Alex notes, there is no problem with having more response categories than predictors (what would be problematic would be having more predictors than *observations*). It looks like your main problem is strange responses. I'm afraid we won't be able to help you unless you provide much more information. Have you looked at the parameter estimates of your multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your help in diagnosing my model issues. I've decided to edit the question to focus on the theoretical question.

Comment: "too few predictors" could cause the system to be *over*-determined, not underdetermined (which would be "too many predictors", relative to the number of observations)

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly answered in comments, some summary here.

First, this last version contains a formulation "In multinomial regression, is it theoretically possible to have issues with having **fewer** predictors than responses?" should probably be **more** as that is more consistent with the first versions. (fewer should definitely not be a problem) but the comparison in the quote is to "responses", not to "(number of) observations", so it is still unclear what is meant.

I will try to answer to the possible versions of Q:

1. More predictors than number of response categories: This is not in itself a problem, as you mostly have many parallel regression equations, linked by the requirement that sum of estimated probs should be one.
2. More predictors than number of observations: This is more of a problem, since the estimating equations are underdetermined, with infinitely many solutions. If the goal is *inference* on model parameters, this is definitely a problem, you should get more data. If the goal is *prediction* of future observations, you could try regularization, such as lasso, ridge or elasticnet (implemented in `R` in CRAN package `glmnet`).